# How I can change the reply-to address in Evolution?

Tags: evolution, email

When I send an e-mail with Evolution the recipient reads,

```
from mypopmail@domain.com
reply to mymail@otherdomain.com
```

I want to it like this

```
from mymail@domain.com
reply to mymail@domain.com
```

How I can change this?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the `reply-to` setting on your mail account then do this.

1. In Evolution goto `Edit` -> `Preferences`.

   [image]
2. In the `Mail Accounts` page select the account you want it changed and hit the `Edit` button.

   [image]
3. On the `Identity` tab set the email address you want to set as your reply address in the `Reply-To` input field.

   [image]
4. Hit `Ok`.

Comment: So, if I just sometimes want to add a reply-to address (because I sometimes send a mail as a specific role), I always have to change this field in the preferences and afterwards change it back again?  This sounds a little tedious.  Isn’t there an easier option?

Comment: AH, found it!  I will add my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the Compose Message window in the View menu you can select to see the `Reply-To Field`.  Then you can set an arbitrary value for the Reply-To header for this message.